# Simple core data relationship load

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have two entities: **Item** and **Note**.
[image]

assign the relationship when I save

```
Item *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Note *note = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

note.noteText = @"test";

[note setInItem:item]; //set relationship??
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // write to database
```

When I load the data, Item attributes are loaded, but I do not know how to load the note.noteText for this item.

```
self.itemNameTextField.text = self.item.name;
...
...
self.itemNoteTextField.text = ????????????
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have defined "containNote" as "to-many" relationship, which means that there can be multiple notes for one item. So what exactly do you mean by "note.noteText for this item" ?

Comment: Right, note.noteText is a NSString, and for example I wrote "test". When I load the data, in the itemNoteTextField should appear "test"

Comment: Can more than one "note" belong to the same "item" ?

Comment: So if an item has more than one note, which text should be displayed?

Comment: noteText which is the attribute of Notes, which is related to Item

Comment: If item as three notes: note1 with "text1", note2 with "text2" and note3 with "text3", what you do want to display?

Comment: in self.itemNoteTextField.text the note1, in self.itemNoteTextField2.text the note2, ecc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17618/discussion-between-vins-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `item` is an *Item* object then `item.containNote` is the set of all related *Note* objects. You can iterate over the notes with

```
for (Note *note in item.containNote) {
    NSString *text = note.Text;
    // Now you can create a text field for this note and display the text ... 
}
```